# How to show the existence, or lack thereof, for $\lim_{x \to 0} \frac{1}{x}\sin\left(\frac{1}{x}\right)$

Tags: real-analysis, calculus, limits, trigonometry

> Does the following limit exist?
> $$\lim_{x \to 0} \frac{1}{x}\sin\left(\frac{1}{x}\right)$$

If yes, then I have to find it; if no, then I need to give reason why.

I couldn’t figure out how to prove this formally, can someone please help me out.

Edit: please note that sin is multiplied by 1/x here and not x.

Comment: Hint : when the $\sin$ function is $1$, the function is $f(y) = \frac 1y$. When the $\sin$ function is $0$ the function is $f(y) = 0$. These don't have the same limit, and $f(x) = \frac 1x \sin \frac 1x$ kind of keeps going from one to the other.

Comment: No, I have 1/x as the multiplier here th question you refer to has only x

Comment: What are then limits along $x=\frac 1 {n\pi}$ and $x=\frac 1 {2n\pi+\frac {\pi} 2}$?

Comment: See also: [How to understand that the $\lim_{x\to 0}\frac1x\cos(\frac1x)$ does not exist.](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/637887), [Limit of $\frac{1}{x} \sin(\frac{1}{x})$](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/2588814). I tried searching in Approach Zero: [version 1](https://approach0.xyz/search/?q=%24%5Clim_%7Bx%20%5Cto%200%7D%20%5Cfrac%7B1%7D%7Bx%7D%5Csin%5Cleft(%5Cfrac%7B1%7D%7Bx%7D%5Cright)%24&p=1), 
[version 2](https://approach0.xyz/search/?q=%24%5Clim_%7Bx%20%5Cto%200%7D%20%5Cfrac%7B1%7D%7Bx%7D%5Csin%5Cfrac%7B1%7D%7Bx%7D%24&p=1).

Comment: You can try both versions [in SearchOnMath](https://www.searchonmath.com/result?query=%24%7B%5Clim_%7Bx+%5Cto+0%7D+%5Cfrac%7B1%7D%7Bx%7D%5Csin%5Cleft%28%5Cfrac%7B1%7D%7Bx%7D%5Cright%29%7D%24&page=1&tm=0&domains=). See also: [How to search on this site?](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/29265)

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Limit of $\frac{1}{x} \sin(\frac{1}{x})$](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2588814/limit-of-frac1x-sin-frac1x)

Answer (score 2):

Define the sequences $(x_n)$ and $(y_n)$ by
$$x_n = \frac{1}{n\pi}\: \text{ and } \: y_n = \frac{1}{\left(2n+\frac{1}{2}\right)\pi}$$
for each $n\in\mathbb{N}$. Clearly, $x_n,y_n\to0$ as $n\to\infty$. Now, it is easy to see that
$$\lim_{n\to\infty}\frac{1}{x_n}\sin\left(\frac{1}{x_n}\right)=0\:\text{ and }\:\lim_{n\to\infty}\frac{1}{y_n}\sin\left(\frac{1}{y_n}\right)=\infty$$
Thus, the limit does not exist.